Update to FOR Wallet from 5-
We received a message about the new FOP Wallet functionality instead of the old "5-" functionality, the notes also say that the functionality is available in the latest versions of SOAP API methods, for example CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ and others. But I also see support for Basic_FOR in these methods. Is it necessary to upgrade to the new version, or is it possible to leave the use of the old element in the SOAP API if our agency uses only the CASH payment method?
Did not try, yet, but mean this element
\<AirPrice\>

\<PriceComparison AmountSpecified="2250"\>

\<AcceptablePriceDecrease HaltOnNonAcceptablePrice="true"\>

\<Amount\>250\</Amount\>

\</AcceptablePriceDecrease\>

\</PriceComparison\>

\<PriceRequestInformation Retain="true"\>

\<OptionalQualifiers\>

\<FOP_Qualifiers\>

\<BasicFOP Type="CK"/\>

\</FOP_Qualifiers\>

\<PricingQualifiers\>

\<NameSelect NameNumber="1.1"/\>

\<PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/\>

\<SpecificPenalty\>

\<Changeable Any="true" BeforeDeparture="true"/\>

\</SpecificPenalty\>

\</PricingQualifiers\>

\</OptionalQualifiers\>

\</PriceRequestInformation\>

\</AirPrice\>

